# How synchronous can a number of electrical clocks in separate devices remain?

Tags: oscillator, clock, crystal, piezo, synchronous

Imagine we have 5 circuits/devices and in each we have an electrical clock that generates a pulse (for example with a constant frequency of 100 Hz or 1 kHz).

In the beginning we have wired all the devices together in order to synchronize the clocks.

After synchronization, we remove the wires and the 5 circuits run independently, with hopefully synchronized clocks.

My question is: since even in the beginning they may not be perfectly synchronized, what can our expectation be usually? Or how perfect/synchronized can these clocks remain?

It is completely of my choice what type of clock or technology to use and is also my question which provides the most synchronous result.

I wonder for example if the clocks even at the beginning may have around a 1 μs delay compared to each other, or if even we can do better than this, or how much this delay may grow after a few hours or what's the best we can achieve with what is in the market for it.

Here are a few specifications that may provide clarification, though I would not observe them as hard specifications, but rather flexible.

1. Maximum deviation after 2 hours: 1 μs or 500 ns
2. Maximum deviation after 1 minute: 200 ns
3. Used to sync a number of camera chip frames' acquisition, a few meters apart
4. The setup can vibrate (like a small electrical motor, toy, drone, etc.)
5. Maximum cost $1500 (is more flexible)

----edit:

6. Hard-wire(e.g., coax) support is possible only every 60 minutes cycles to help resynchronization/fine-tuning. Basically, all clocks should be sync with a master to which they are allowed to hard-wire only every 60 minutes, disconnect again and leave freely again until the next hour.
7. Wireless supports are optional to help with synchronization (e.g.,  Synchornization signals between cameras, or from a master refrence).
8. The vibration problem may be alleviated using some mechanical low-pass filter over which the circuit is mounted.
9. Acoustic signals are not possible.
10. The master reference does not vibrate and is temperature compensated and can use atomic clocks.
11. In each separate free runing circuit, it is also possible to have multiple clocks whose output are combined (e.g., averaged over time or filterred) in order to give a more accurage sync.
12. circuit size of each free-running node should fit in a 10x10cm box and not weigh more than 500 grams. Though I would hope the technology is scalable to lower values.

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (see the link below). -- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142135/discussion-on-question-by-azerila-how-synchrounous-can-a-number-of-electrical-cl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clock crystals are electromechanical devices: oscillation frequency depends on temperature, vibration, acceleration, supply voltage, etc. For example putting a cotton ball on a non temperature compensated crystal oscillator will change its drift characteristics by making temperature more constant (less air movement). It also has pink noise and "random walk" so over a period of hours, crystal oscillators will drift. How much depends on which oscillator is used.

But if you want 0.1ppb drift then you need [atomic clocks](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/products/clock-and-timing/components/atomic-clocks/embedded-atomic-oscillators) which are not cheap.

Now, as is often the case there is a lot of information missing in the question. For example, you say synchronization is extremely important, but you ask for deviations that are extremely easy to achieve for almost no cost if all the systems are connected together with wires or by other means of synchronization, yet very difficult and expensive if all the systems use free-running oscillators. And then you say you want to use free-running oscillators without explaining why.

If the asker doesn't take time to explain the reasons behind such an exotic and unusual requirement to use free-running oscillators, then it probably means it's not important, so I'll ignore it.

So, I'll propose the following options:

- Connect everything together with coax. A pulse on a coax can arrive with picosecond precision ; however due to temperature drift and cable movement stretching the cable slightly it will vary a little bit. Still way below your requirement, so it'll be fine.
- If no cables are possible, then optical fibers. Any $1 TORX optical receiver will meet the 500ns requirement over plastic fiber.
- If no physical connection is possible, then either optical, radio, or sound.

Since cameras are involved, I suppose the experiment takes place in a medium that allows the transmission of light. If it's not vacuum, sound can be transmitted. Radio might upset some sensitive physics equipment. In all these three cases, a modulated wave can be transmitted and received to synchronize the devices. This does not need to happen constantly: if the devices are synchronized often enough, the requirement over the long-time drift of local oscillators is reduced substantially, making cheap crystal oscillators an option.

Some radio protocols already handle clock synchronization, for example bluetooth, but it doesn't seem accurate enough for your needs (>1µs error).

A master device can transmit the current timestamp to all devices. Or each slave device can emit a signal which the master receives, and then the master tells the device at which timestamp the signal was received, so the device knows its own time offset relative to the others.

If it has to be wireless and not take too much time to implement, personally I would look for a readymade solution using a radio protocol that already encodes time with sufficient accuracy and offers exploitable output signals. Preferably it should be available at mass market price: wireless audio, wireless video, etc.

Another option would be to take advantage of the fact that cameras require light. No matter how long the shutter is open, if the scene is illuminated by a short flash from one single light source, then all the pictures taken by all the cameras will be perfectly synchronized as they will only capture light during that flash. It is not trivial to pulse high power LEDs quickly due to their capacitance, but it is doable and that could be an interesting low-budget solution. In addition the devices can detect flashes with a light sensor to synchronize their clocks.

I should also mention that you should check the aperture jitter and latency in your cameras and other acquisition devices.

Comment: Very nicely written; I think our answers complement each other  well!

Comment: Thanks! I hope OP will reveal the reason for this surprising requirement of using free-running oscillators...

Comment: I do as well; it was kind of a long process until OP saw the need to actually define requirements, and it wasn't great that they consider it "soft requirements" still, instead of actually saying something like "worse than this, and my system won't work"; I have the same problem as you: Unless these are really expensive high-speed cameras (in which case the 1500$ constraint would seem disproportionate, and in which case they would surely already come with synchronization ports), an accuracy below microseconds for a camera makes, hm, infinitesimal amounts of sense. But it's all we have :(

Comment: @bobflux thank you for the comprehensive and informative answer. The oscilators have to be free-running unfortunately, however, every hour, I can make a wire connection to a master to resync the oscilator, disconnect, and leave it free running again. In general all oscilators should be sync with a master to which they can only wire-connect every hour. I added an edit to describe this a bit more. Sorry for my inclear description, the thing is electronics is not my field really and I am trying my best to define requirements and find out what's close to them in terms of possiblity.

Comment: the master can have an CSAC atomic clock

Comment: again, Heisenberg strikes: You can only know a frequency exactly if you observe it for long; you can't have short observation (i.e. exact knowledge of time) and exact knowledge of frequency at the same time. How long your "connected to main clock" time within your 60 min period is puts a *very* hard limit on how exact you can synchronize the slave and the master clock within that window. This all sounds very much like you should distribute a clock, continously, via radio or laser beam to your devices.

Comment: @azerila you should give more details about the experiment so we understand why those requirements exist. But you say wireless is possible, so if wireless synchronization is an option it will be the best solution. What kind of wireless, optical or radio?

Comment: @bobflux both optical and radio would be possible but, there might be obstacles between the nodes that may cause a bit of refraction/reflection, etc. The scene is rather cluttered. maybe this earlier question of mine helps:

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53884/how-simultaneous-can-we-trigger-multiple-cameras-frame-acquisition/

Comment: like if all the cameras look at a set of LEDS points. The goal is knowing the position of the LEDs in the farme and the LEDs move/vibrate. The goal is all cameras get an as simoultaneous frame as possible that serves the same information from them. Like if the target changes a text with a high frequency all cameras (global shutter) capture a frame with the same text. @MarcusMüller

Comment: detours and multipath are a technologically solvable problem for communications, but not problematic for frequency reference purposes under high SNR conditions (as yours would be), so that's a good thing that you can do that. I pointed this out be for but "XYZ as possible" is not something that a physicist or engineer can act upon. Model until you have hard limits that you need; then check whether these are attainable.

Comment: one has to wonder though – now that you come around with more of these specifics, why we're even talking about all this: a broadband trigger signal transmitted wirelessly might alleviate most of these problems, modulo speed of light and distance. There's literally no need for exact oscillators in all these devices.

Comment: Why no wires? Are the cameras flying on drones?

Comment: @MarcusMüller true but I am not sure how more complex the solution might be then. There can be a wireless reciever which it is not clear for me how much uncertainty the reciever may add in terms of converting the wireless trigger to the electrical trigger. Because of this I think for a number of clocks that are initially wired and synchronized, it may be easy to have them remaining in sync for at least an hour after wire-detachement. The cluttered environment also adds a question for me if refraction/reflection may influence the performance. it is a very cluttered environment.

Comment: Do you have hard requirements that say the other solution (which, by the way, I'd presume will end up much harder) is sufficient? @azerila static clutter doesn't matter.

Comment: @bobflux not really, in general the cameras are within a very cluttered work-space, and may move at somepoint, sometimes wiring isn't possible or very hard, or sometimes involves considerable tedious process to rewire. Just bringing back the camera close to the master reference seems easiest for resync.

Comment: @azerila multiple people have now said that wireless synchronization is the easiest solution. as you're clearly not the expert here, why do you insist that you can in fact synchronize more easily by *carrying around something that needs an immense accuracy*, and *short-term trying to synchronize it*, which, again, mathematically is simply not possible?

Comment: @MarcusMüller depends on how static we talk about. Like in a factory environment for example there might be many vibrations around also. sometimes industry doesn't easily show appetite for wireless solutions. Any solution other than constant wire connection is open (unless the wire connection only every hour for resync). It's just the challenges of wireless technology that led me think maybe it's easier to keep a number of free running clocks sync for at least an hour.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do aggree on the statements that perhaps wireless method would be better. It's just industry is sometimes too strict about them, but I may end of seening the best solution.

Comment: You're making up new scenarios/requirements as we speak. Honestly, I think I'll just leave you alone – bobflux and I gave you plenty of input, must have asked for you to actually come up with actual requirements for a combined dozen of times already, and you still do this "oh I can imagine that what the expert say isn't right, because of this new thing". This takes us nowhere. Even if you were paying me as a consultant, we'd be reaching the point where I'd start to re-negotiate because this is so frustrating.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do appreciate your inputs so far, they have been helpful. I have really tried/trying my best also in terms of descriptions, though I haven't really made up descriptions. Industry is really hard on wireless solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in bed on my phone, but because I think you at least deserve a stub of an answer:

With your requirements 1. and 2., which, not having any other indication to go on, I'll have to take as hard requirements, no matter how much you like to see them as soft, we can deduct limits:

Over \$7.2\cdot10^{3}\$ s, you can accept an error \$5\cdot10^{-7}\$ s, which means you need an oscillator with a frequency accuracy of \$5/7.2\cdot10^{-7-3}\$, so in the order of \$10^{-10}\$, or 0.1 ppb.

That. Is. Hard. Normal quartzes don't achieve that kind of accuracy, not even temperature-compensated ones, and even using oven-controlled oscillators (OCXO), you will have not a trivial time.

At 1500 $ per synchronized device, you can try to go and combine a very *stable* quartz oscillator, usually an OCXO with a GPS receiver, which uses GPS to ever do slightly nudge the oscillator to run a bit faster or slower, should it run differently than GPS time. GPS works by solving a system with four unknowns (namely, three coordinates and time of the receiver) by observing (at least) 4 known signals from 4 different satellites with sufficiently known path (but initially unknown local time and thus position). Such GPSDOs (GPS-disciplined oscillators) can be commercially bought; that's mostly do to the fact that cellular best stations need a similar degree of synchronicity as you.

Note, however, that these stations are much further away from each other than a few meters, such that directly feeding in the same clock signal to multiple stations becomes hard. (You directly run into mathematically the same thing that you know as Heisenberg uncertainty - can't know your frequency domain position and your spatial domain position arbitrarily precisely at the same time. Hope that strikes a bell for you as physicist!)

So, you've got closely co-situated devices. Usually, everyone would just tell you to run coax cables from a central clock distributor everywhere, and then let all the clocks have the same, and thus, pairwise approximately zero, error.

But the fact that you're exposed to vibrations can make that mechanically hard - and oscillator-wise even harder: if the mechanical vibration effects a Doppler effect on the signal traveling the clock cable, that literally modulates your observed oscillator frequency - and you observe a red shift or blue shift away from your nominal frequency; of which you can, again, only tolerate \$10^{-10}\$! So that's going to take a bit of modelling to see whether you can tolerate that — you probably can, because I've long terms, you'd expect the dilation and contractions to be zero-mean, but you should definitely sit down and model that.

By the way, even if you end up building a system with local oscillators, every shape of quartz oscillator is an acoustic component and works by forming a oscillator that exchanges energy between mechanical stress in a crystal lattice and electrical potential at a relatively well-definable speed. So, such crystal oscillators are inherently sensitive to external acceleration, i.e., especially vibration.

So all in all, looking a bit deeper into my crystal ball, this sounds like a job for a good OCXO at each of your devices, together with control loop that gets informed about one central frequency standard, which *can* be GPS, but it could also be one local reference oscillator distributed to every device, used with a very low bandwidth to adjust the speed of the local oscillators, such that the mechanical vibrations are filtered out by virtue of being too high in frequency.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. using GPS signals from sattelights are unfortunately not possible, but what is possible is signals from a master reference nearby that does not vibrate and is temperature compensated or has atomic clock. I can also wire-connect the free-running circuits every hour with this reference to resync them again and let them free. Also between the cameras (separate sircuits signals are possible).

Comment: see my comments under bobflux' answer. The disconnect/reconnect thing is probably not a great idea. Instead, distribute your clock wirelessly. Again, all already said a few minutes ago under bobflux' answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Injection locking* is one mechanism where two remote oscillators can synchronize to the same frequency. For example, a **regenerative radio receiver** can have its weak local oscillator *frequency-lock* to the incoming antenna signal. Within the lock-in range, phase does vary. The lock-in range depends on relative signal strength and also depends on stability of oscillator(s) frequency. When carefully tuned, a 10 MHz regen receiver can injection-lock to WWV's carrier from a considerable distance (1000km). Be aware that *very careful* tuning is required to achieve lock.

Imagine TWO regenerative radio receivers, tuned to the same frequency. Each receiver has a short antenna attached so that it can receive its mate. Since a simple regenerative receiver is basically an oscillator with antenna coupled in, each receiver is also a weak transmitter when it is adjusted to weakly oscillate. They will tend to injection-lock to each other, and remain locked until separated by some distance.

Regarding pulses, I have observed that two digital clocks can lock to one another. The one-second pulse advancing the "seconds" hand can electromagnetically influence the 32768 Hz crystal oscillator of the other clock. A similar effect to injection-locking.
When the battery voltage of the crystal oscillator drops from old age, the two clocks are likely to un-lock because the crystal oscillator frequency is also influenced by the battery's dropping voltage. Not a mechanism easily engineered...

The old NTSC colour TV system modulates an RF carrier with synchronizing pulses and bursts used in a few locking systems:

- Colour burst (3.579 MHz) phase-locks to reproduce proper colour
- Horizontal sync pulse
- Vertical sync pulse

Comment: 1000km seems an overkill for a problem that involves only a few meters (less than 5 or 10). I basically have a few cmos camera chips in the vicinity of a few meters that I want to trigger as simoultaneous as possible (make their frames as simoultaneous as possible). the frequncy would not be very important for me, any frequency about 10Hz is enough. but important would be as simoultaneous pulses as possible

Comment: @azerila In the case of two antenna-coupled oscillators (regenerative receivers), one would want a high frequency to maintain sync, because drift of either oscillator causes phase-shift...at 10 MHz, a phase slip of one cycle causes a time offset of 0.1us. OTOH, high frequency oscillators more easily drift from age, temperature or proximity to passing people.